# Django HTML form input to db.sqlite3

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a simple web server to take html input data and insert it to data base table .

I've tried with POST request got into more CSRF troubles , Turned to GET request to go over CSRF (not necessary in my case ) , still not able to GET the html data into Database .

myapp/models.py

```py
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

myapp/templates/createpost.html

```html
<head>
<title>Create a Post </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Create a Post </h1>
<form action="" method="GET">
    {%csrf_token%}
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br/>
    Content: <br/>
    <textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="content">
        </textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

myapp/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post


def createpost(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('title', None) and request.GET.get('content', None):
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.GET.get('title', None)
            post.content = request.GET.get('content', None)
            post.save()
        return render(request, 'createpost.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'createpost.html')
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='createpost.html'), name='createpost'),
]
```

am using Django 2.2.6 with PyCharm community  2019.2.3 
I've been searching for almost 2 days , checked django doc , and stackoverflow answers , none was helpful , I had to ask to make sure its not a version related issue and forgive me if i miss understand a simple point am just a beginner.

Comment: have you tried printing this? `request.GET.get('title', None)` is it empty or None? what do you get?

Comment: i have no idea how to do that , i ve tried python manage.py runserver and then call the view.py on another terminal and i could not , i tried to add print command to the view and i get no output at all

Comment: ok, what I meant is, do `print(request.GET.get('title', None))` and submit the form again and check

Comment: i did , and there is no print at all , all i get is my GET request 

[02/Oct/2019 03:00:01] "GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken=Q0FAgroc1JbIOfKImoTIcMiX4qv1AGVYIy9quUdPSu16ttR1NGRvQFhvEK3IBa6o&title=george&content=george++++++++ HTTP/1.1" 200 440

which am trying to extract title and content from .

Comment: Show your URLs. Almost certainly you are not sending to the createpost view. But you should be using POST here anyway.

Comment: Edited and added , i ve tried with post check every possible solution to CSRF problem and still cant manage to submit.

Comment: I ll move to POST after i get it figured out with GET , when its done with GET i know that my only problem is  with CSRF token and i can figure it out , if i posted the question with the CSRF token no found , answers will focus on that , that's the only reason i switched to GET request , and if u have noticed my code its all named POST , but thanks for the advice anyway i know how dangerous it is .

Comment: If you only want to bypass csrf validation for a moment so you can debug another issue, you can use the [csrf_exampt decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) on your view. And your code snippet IS using GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried with POST request got into more CSRF troubles , Turned to GET request to go over CSRF (not necessary in my case ) , still not able to make it .

Ok.

**STOP EVERYTHING RIGHT NOW**

Now

1. do the official Django tutorial and learn to use Django forms and modelforms
2. read the HTTP spec about the proper use of GET requests (hint: the important word here is "idempotent")
3. fix your code accordingly
4. if by then you **still** have issues with the csrf token, come back and post a question about it (with a proper MCVE etc).

Also note that your question should be claused as either unclear or OT since you didn't explain what your **problem** is (hint: "doesn't work" doesn't explain anything). But anyway...

What you want (nb: models unchanged) is:

myapp/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Post
        fields = ("title", "content")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from . models import Post
from . forms import PostForm

def createpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # read the doc for `redirect` and change the destination to
            # something that makes sense for your app.
            # as to why we redirect, cf  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
            return redirect("/")

    else:
        # GET request, present an empty form
        form = PostForm() 
    return render(request, 'createpost.html', {"form": form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

# NB: actually you should define myapp's urls in 
# myapp/urls.py and `include` them here
from myapp.views import createpost

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', createpost, name='createpost'),
]
```

myapp/templates/createpost.html

```
<head>
  <title>Create a Post </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Create a Post </h1>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
   </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't garantee this will work out of the box (I'd have to post a full project with proper settings etc to be sure - and actually to test it at least once for typos etc) but that's the correct way of doing things.

> I've been searching for almost 2 days

That's 2 days wasted, that you would have better used doing the official Django tutorial. I also suggest you learn to debug programs - just adding a couple ̀print("XXX")` calls in your view and checking your devserver's outputs would have made clear why nothing got created in your database (hint: with your original urls.py, you are NEVER calling your view function).

Comment: Thanks for the advice , i have read a lot of the doc .djangoproject but not as a series just a few topic related , i thought i had a good background apparently not .
i've tried to debug with print , but had no idea how to call django view function .

Comment: @George that's why you should really to do the (whole!) tutorial first - it guides you into creating a simple project, so you can get the whole picture before diving into deeper details. The only caveats are the tutorial insistance on using generic class-based views (which are most of the time nothing but a useless complication that only confuses beginners), and the fact it doesn't present django forms and modelforms (which are actually a _very_ important part of Django).

Comment: yes , i totally agree now , your answer was more helpful than 2 days random reading and searching . i ll follow the tutorial for now . and really thanks for spending your time to help a beginner like me .

Comment: @George you're welcome. I kindly suggest you also take time to learn basic debugging technics (how to trace code execution, inspect current program state etc - IOW using the step debugger), this will save you a _lot_ of time when things don't work as expected - which is, actually, the most common case ;-)